# Append variable to element and start from scratch after user input pausing

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

What I have achieved so far: Append a string to a target element as well as limiting the possible characters.

```
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
   var s = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
   if (s.match(/[a-zA-Z\.]/))
     $("#input p").append(s);
   console.log(s + ' is a match!');
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ngac8wj5/7/

What I am struggling with:
How to implement a method of reseting the target elements html content on user input if the user has paused for a duration X.

Any ideas how to approach this?
Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After spending more time on this i seem to have partly achieved the desired behaviour, there are somehow unexpected phenomena still where it cleans the container way sooner than expected.

```
var timeout;
var lapsed = false;

function cleanUp(e){
  lapsed = true
};

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  timeout = setTimeout(cleanUp, 1500)

  if(lapsed == true ) {
    $("#input p").empty();
  }

  if(timeout) {
    lapsed = false
    var s = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (s.match(/[a-zA-Z\.]/))
      $("#input p").append(s);
    console.log(s);
  } else {
    cleanUp();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ngac8wj5/76/